# DllNotFoundException libpjsipDll Mono

Tags: dll, mono, environment-variables, sip

I've a problem to execute a program with Mono in the terminal, (mono program.exe). An error appears : "System.DllNotFoundException : libpjsipDll.so "

however my library exists and I've setted my 2 environment variables : LD_LIBRARY_PATH and MONO_PATH in the directory where the file is.

I don't understand why this error occured ?

Anyone has an idea ?

I've :

ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped (CPU architecture)

ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),dynamically linked, not stripped (third-party lib)

I try MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" MONO_LOG_MASK="dll".

and I obtain an : undefined symbol : Pa_GetErrorText

I try to install PortAudio but I doesn't work always :-(

Thanks in advance.

Narglix

Comment: Did you solve this? Im having the same issue with Ubuntu 12. I copied my libpjsipDll.so in /usr/bin and /usr/local/lib and then I used $ sudo lbconfig but nothing happends! mono is still not finding the libpjsipDll.so

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the letter casing is correct in that the library you are calling and the assembly on disk have the same case. Linux is picky about it.

I assume that you are using P/Invoke DLLImport? What is the actual code you are using here? You library (libpjsipDll.so) is not managed code of course.

Comment: [DllImportAttribute("libpjsipDll.so", EntryPoint = "onRegStateCallback")]
    private static extern int onRegStateCallback(OnRegStateChanged cb);

Answer (score 0):

Is not a problem about loading, is a problem about another dependency dll, just run this code and make sure the **libpjsipDll.so** is where the **callingApp.exe** is executing.

> //I tried this in ubuntu $ sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386

I discovered that running my App like this:

```
$ MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono MyApp.exe
```

Here is my question, where you can find adittional info:
[MonoDevelop and libpjsipDll.so library on Ubuntu. System.DllNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726457/monodevelop-and-libpjsipdll-so-library-on-ubuntu-system-dllnotfoundexception)