# MonoDevelop and libpjsipDll.so library on Ubuntu. System.DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, monodevelop, ubuntu-14.04

i am trying to use a dll for Linux called: **libpjsipDll_v44.so**
I got it from here http://code.google.com/p/sipeksdk/downloads/list

It's a port for Linux of the http://www.pjsip.org/ is a VOIP library

This site claims that is posible to use the library in Linux
https://sites.google.com/site/sipekvoip/Home/documentation/pjsipwrapper/pjsipwrapper-for-linux

The code in **MonoDevelop 4.0.12** with **C#** the code is like this:

```
internal const string PJSIP_DLL = "libpjsipDll.so"; 

[DllImportAttribute(PJSIP_DLL, EntryPoint = "onRegStateCallback")]
private static extern int onRegStateCallback(OnRegStateChanged cb);
```

But is not working! it throw **System.DllNotFoundException**

I'm working with **Ubuntu x86 v14.04 lts**
This are the steps I did to install the library:

```
$ sudo cp libpjsipDll_v44.so /usr/lib/libpjsipDll.so 
$ sudo ldconfig
```

I even tried to copy the library to several more paths like

```
/usr/local/lib 
/lib`
```

and create links

```
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpjsipDll.so /usr/lib/libpjsipDll_v44.so
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpjsipDll.so /usr/lib/pjsipDll.so
```

Then trying to look for my .so installed i run this command:

```
$ sudo ldconfig -p |grep libpjsipDll
```

[image]
I also tryied to map the dll using **App.config** using as many combination i can think of wihtout success

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <dllmap dll="libpjsipDll.so" target="libpjsipDll.so"/>
  <!--
  <dllmap dll="libpjsipDll.so" target="/libpjsipDll.so"/>
  <dllmap dll="libpjsipDll.so" target="/usr/lib/libpjsipDll.so"/>
  <dllmap dll="libpjsipDll.so" target="/usr/local/lib/libpjsipDll.so"/>
  <dllmap dll="libpjsipDll.so" target="i:libpjsipDll.so"/>
  <dllmap dll="libpjsipDll.so" target="libpjsipDll.so" wordsize="32" cpu="x86"/>
  -->
</configuration>
```

I tried executing the .exe like this:

```
$ MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono MyApp.exe
```

and i realice that the application needed an other dll **libssl0**

Then I installed the required dll, and everything run fine! but I still cant make any call.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
```

I have used this same dll (extension .dll) with .NET in Windows without any problem!
Any idea what am i doing wrong?

[image: The error]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if this helps you... http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllmap/